# What is a trick procedure does?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to update the value in MySQL DB, so in order to do it I use procedure.

There is my DB

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `manager_name` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `num_works` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `num_jobs` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=306
;
```

There is my procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `session_update_works_num`(
    IN `id` INT,
    IN `num_works` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'use this procedure to update works num'
BEGIN
UPDATE `gmdb`.`sessions` SET `num_works`=num_works WHERE  `id`=id;
END
```

There is how I use it in my C# code

```
protected override void Execution()
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = DBConnection.Instance.Connection)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = PROCEDURE_UPDATE_WORKS_NUM;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{Constants.SESSION_TABLE_ID}", SessionSingleton.Instance.SessionId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{Constants.SESSION_TABLE_NUM_WORKS}", m_worksNum);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SetTaskStatus(State.COMPLETED);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMsg += $"ERROR: while execute procedure : {PROCEDURE_UPDATE_WORKS_NUM}, error: {e.ToString()}";
            SetTaskStatus(State.FAILED);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if for example, I have a few lines in my DB

[image]

After the procedure will be executed `num_works` field will be changed for all the lines.

[image]

But if I change the code and use a query instead of a procedure all works fine:

```
protected override void Execution()
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = TV_DP_DBConnection.Instance.Connection)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                string query = $"UPDATE `gmdb`.`sessions` SET `num_works`={m_worksNum} WHERE  `id`={SessionSingleton.Instance.SessionId};";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SetTaskStatus(State.COMPLETED);
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMsg += $"ERROR: while execute procedure : {PROCEDURE_UPDATE_WORKS_NUM}, error: {e.ToString()}";
            SetTaskStatus(State.FAILED);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem here? How is it possible that I pass to procedure exact id `WHERE  'id'=id` but all the lines have an effect?

Comment: I don't use mysql, but it looks to me like the `WHERE` clause is comparing the id column to itself instead of to the parameter. Maybe your quoting is wrong. Also try changing the name of the parameter to disambiguate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CrowCoder is right, variable names in stored procedure are the same as column names. Change variable names both in SP and code, and try again.